# Query to show all expired records from today to two weeks from now

Tags: php, sql

I need help with a sql query. I do not know SQL at all, but I am trying to use a line of SQL within my database to run an insurance report.

I want to see every vendor whose insurance is expiring between today and two weeks from now.  Once I put the query in the date field, I can then set the report up to run automatically every two weeks and send me a copy.

Therefore, every two weeks I can see what vendors insurance is expiring.

Here is the SQL:

```
sql=(SELECT vndrinsrnce_dte_end FROM vndrinsrnce WHERE 
     vndrinsrnce_dte_end > SYSDATE AND vndrinsrnce_dte_end < SYSDATE +14)
```

It gives me an error.  Can anyone help?

Attached is is a picture of the field I am trying to enter it in.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: Can you change the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE vndrinsrnce_dte_end BETWEEN SYSDATE() AND SYSDATE() + 14` and try.

Answer (score 0):

sysdate is Oracle, try GETDATE() instead for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best way to do it, considering GETDATE() returns time of day, which you will likely want to ignore. It adds 13 days, so that on the 14th day when you run it again there will be no overlap.

```
SELECT vndrinsrnce_dte_end
FROM vndrinsrnce
WHERE vndrinsrnce_dte_end between CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 13, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause in @LordOfSQL's answer is correct, however the question states:

> I want to see every vendor whose insurance is expiring between today and two weeks from now.

Your SQL statement is only retrieving the the policy expiration date, not any actual usable information about the vendor. Therefore, you will need to update your SELECT statement to include all of the columns you need in order to identify the vendor, such as:

```
SELECT [vendor_name], [vendor_phone] -- Just replace the names in [] with the actual column names
FROM vndrinsrnce
WHERE vndrinsrnce_dte_end between CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 13, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```